# tap gesture recognizer does not get fire

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to implement an action, when if the user tap somewhere on the screen, then the keyboard should disappear.

I have an app, that look as follow
[image]

When I tap on textfield then the keyboard appears, that is good.
Now I want, when I tap somewhere on the screen, then the keyboard should disappear.
I implemented a tap gesture recognizer with following property value:
[image] 
[image]

And the tap gesture recognizer I bound with following action in the view controller

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func textFieldDoneEdition(sender: UITextField) {
        sender.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    @IBAction func onTapGestureRecognized(sender: AnyObject) {

        nameField.resignFirstResponder()
        numberField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

}
```

Tap gesture recognizer is bound to the function.
[image]
And it does not work at all, when I tap somewhere on the screen. The keyboard is still there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you drag the touch gesture recognizer onto the view ? and is the function actually called ?

Comment: I updated my post, consider the last picture. I set the break point in the function, it does not stop, when tap somewhere on the screen.

Comment: First of all the breakpoints will never be hit because they are not active (in order for them to be active they need to be blue (not faded)). Click them once again to make them blue.

Comment: yes, I made them blue and run the app again. It does not stop at set break-point. The `onTapGestureRecognized` function is not called all.

Comment: can you try to remove the gesture recognizer and then drag it onto the view again and hook it up again ?

Comment: I tried that in a demo project and it worked for me.

Comment: Yes I deleted it and hook up with the action function again, run and it does not work. How do you do? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's strange ...

Comment: Can you make a screenshot of the connections inspector (the arrow to the very right in your utilities panel) with your tap gesture recognizer selected ?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/5kahv4tcd/

Comment: Now it works. The problem was, I did not drag the tap gesture recognizer over the storyboard, just insert into document outline pane. Thanks so much for help.

Comment: That's what I meant by "dragging it onto the view". You're welcome. Good luck!

Comment: Do I have always drag onto the view? What is the different when I drag it onto document outline pane?

Comment: The difference is that the tap gesture recognizer always has an associated view that it will be attached to. So for example, if you have a subview in your controller (let's say your logo image for example (this is a bad example because `UIImageView`s usually have user interaction disabled (it does not care about touches, but you could enable it))) then only taps on the associated view will be triggered, which is very useful (you don't want the gesture to be recognized all around the other views). The point is, the recognizer will only be recognized in the associated view's frame.

Answer (score 0):

Your view should have the Gesture associated.

[image]

Your Gesture should have `Sent actions`

[image]

This should be enough to work.

If for some mystical reason, none of this works, you have an alternative for dismiss keyboard.

`func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)`